# MySQL search is too "loose"

Tags: php, mysql, search

Alright so I have made a site, just for a project I was doing. On this site I have this database that has a couple of articles on it, I use this code for make queries:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
    $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['summary'];        
        echo $row['content']; 
        echo $row['publicationDate']; 

    }  

}
?>
```

The problem is that the search is a bit too "loose." The database which the site connects to has many articles. What I don't like is that say I searched the letter 'A' in the search box, it comes up with any instance the letter 'A' appears in any article title. So instead of coming with the article for the letter 'A', Australia, Austria, Afghanistan and even Ecuador come up. Its kind of frustrating. Can you help me?

Comment: Remove the first %.... "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '$term."%'";

Comment: This isn't a PHP search, it's an SQL query.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE $term.'%'"; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to force it to be a start of a string or start of a word:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '% ".$term."%' OR title LIKE '".$term."%'";
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, more of a comment, and it isn't correct.  After OR is a syntax error and `OR .. LIKE 'term%'` wouldn't do anything after `LIKE '%term%'`.

Comment: With this code, it will only take words or strings starting with the term, so it will be more accurate results? an the second OR .. LIKE 'term%' is doing something, because of the space before the term in the first check.

btw. I have added LIKE after OR (just a simple oversight).

Comment: Ah, I see that you have the extra space in there.  Still doesn't answer the question because that isn't what they asked, what they asked is still pretty unclear.  But clearly they didn't want things that started with "A".

Comment: i guess your works. it reduced the amount of results displayed drastically.

Comment: If you need more qualified results, you shoul consider using a search system like elastic search or similar.